# Remove space between two Column in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to remove the gap between these two columns.
[image]
How can I achieve this?

This is the code which I tried. The `Expanded()` here is inside the `Row()` widget.
I would like to decrease the gap between the two `Columns()`. I tried wrapping both Columns inside a Container and implementing Padding on it, but it doesn't work. I tried mainAxisAlignment also.

```
                 Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 98.0,
                        child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Room 1',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            subtitle: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.check_box_outline_blank
                                  ),
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.check_box,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 98.0,
                        child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Room 1',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            subtitle: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.check_box_outline_blank
                                  ),
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.check_box,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: please add code whatever you tried.

Comment: I have added the Code

Comment: use Flexible instead of Expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved by using `Flexible()` instead of `Expanded()`.
Thanks to: [Jay Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4818128/jay-patel)